# iTextSharp returns only whitespaces string for specific PDF file

Tags: pdf, itext, text-extraction

I am testing this simple code:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PDF_TXT2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = args[0];

            string pathFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

            string pathFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

            string text = string.Empty;
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
            }
            reader.Close();

            Clipboard.SetText(text);
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }
}
```

This specific [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jlpRqvm3c0UOtM56w2konrutXbnS_aFb/view?usp=sharing) file makes causes an empty string. actually not empty but only full of whitespaces.

Could you help me understand why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The fonts in your PDF have this entry

```
/ToUnicode/Identity-H
```

i.e. the value of **ToUnicode** is the *name* **Identity-H**.

According to the PDF specification, though, the value of **ToUnicode** must be a *stream*!

> **ToUnicode**
> stream
> *(Optional)* A stream containing a CMap file that maps character codes to Unicode values (see 9.10, "Extraction of Text Content").

Thus, the **ToUnicode** mapping in your file is invalid which can result in arbitrary errors during text extraction.

Comment: Could you please tell me where did you find these properties?

Comment: I used a PDF structure browser (iText RUPS in this case) and looked at the contents of the font resources of the PDF page in question.